# Bison resolving shift/reduce conflict when across rules

Tags: bison

If one of my rules expand the same as part of the other rule, how would I mark precedence? For instance, I have `expression IS type` rule that should expand `type` as `type DOT identifier` recursively. But the in the same rule `expression` I have `expression DOT identifier` which bison reports as conflict. I would obviously want all `DOT`s within as expression's type part to reduce together into `type` and not as expression. Ie: `a is b.c.d` should parse as `(a is b.c.d)` where `b.c.d` is `type` and not `(a is b).c.d`. Here is minimal grammar that shows the conflict:

```
%require "3.0"
%defines

%define api.pure full
%define parse.trace

%token DOT '.'
%token IS "is"

%left DOT
%left IS

%%

example
    : expression
    ;
    
expression
    : expression DOT identifier
    | expression IS type
    | identifier
    ;
    
type
    : fqtypename
    ;

fqtypename
    : identifier
    | fqtypename DOT identifier
    ;

identifier: 
    "blah"
    ;

%%
```

and error:

```
State 10

5 type: fqtypename •
7 fqtypename: fqtypename • DOT identifier

DOT  shift, and go to state 12

DOT       [reduce using rule 5 (type)]
$default  reduce using rule 5 (type)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the conflicted state, the conflict actually has nothing to do with the `IS` token. Rather, the conflict is between shifting `DOT` and reducing the production `type: fqtypename`, and you want that to resolve  to shifting `DOT`.

In fact, that's the default resolution without any precedence declarations. Bison, like Yacc, automatically resolves shift-reduce conflicts in favour of shifting, and reduce-reduce conflicts in favour of whichever production appears earlier in the grammar file. You can see that resolution in the state table you pasted (`DOT` is shifted in that state). Of course, that does leave you looking at a bison warning every time you generate your parser, which is not ideal. You can avoid the warning by using an [`%expect` declaration](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Expect-Decl), which basically tells Bison the number of shift-reduce conflicts that are expected to be resolved automatically. With recent Bison versions, you can attach the declaration to the production itself, which makes the expectation more precise. See the link to the Bison manual, which shows an example grammar somewhat similar to yours.

With a bit more work, you can use precedence declarations to achieve the same effect, which has the advantage of being slightly more precise, at the cost of making the grammar a bit more mysterious. Here's an example based on the grammar in your question. Note that a `%prec` declaration is attached to the production which is actually involved in the conflict. Because that production has no terminal symbols at all, it was necessary to use a pseudo-token to represent the precedence level.

```
/* I removed the token names for '.' and "is" to make the grammar shorter. */
%left TYPE_UNIT
%left '.'

%%

example
    : expression
    
expression
    : expression '.' identifier
    | expression "is" type
    | identifier
    
type
    : fqtypename             %prec TYPE_UNIT

fqtypename
    : identifier
    | fqtypename '.' identifier

identifier: 
    "blah"
```

Comment: Thanks! How come when using fqtypename in different rule (such as `KW_DECLARE fqtypename IDENTIFIER SEMICOLON`) there was no conflict?

Comment: @enerccio: Because there's no production for `fqtypename` in which an `IDENTIFIER` could be shifted. Or any other token other than `.`. The parser knows what the possible active productions are; a conflict occurs when the next token is not enough information to decide between shifting and reducing. (Which is equivalent to saying shifting now or shifting later, since every token needs to be shifted; the only question is which production it's shifted into.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Man, I am used to making parsers with antlr4 in Java but there is no C target for antlr4 so i am stuck with bison that seems a bit harder to make correct grammar.

Comment: @enerccio: They are different parsing algorithms and different philosophies. Bison is certainly pickier, but it also sometimes generates the desired parser even though it complains about conflicts. Antlr tries to avoid warnings; it always generates a parser (unless it can't correct for left recursion) but it doesn't always generate the parser you wanted, and since it doesn't warn you about that, you have to rely on your testing. Of course, that's the same with Bison precedence: it can't warn you about precedence declaration errors. But at least it warns about conflicts.

Comment: Also, check out the counterexamples feature added to Bison a couple of release ago, which makes it much easier to track down the cause of conflicts.